# pass information back into included file

Tags: php, include

I have a website that I have set up with includes so its templated. Can I pass information from one page to the included file? Here is the situation, I have a `header.php` I put at the top of them `page.php` file. Header includes all the good stuff like the `head` and nav I need on every page, but how can i pass to the header.php page specific information for better SEO like OG tag stuff and page title stuff?

Header.php

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html lang="en">

    <head>
        <?php require 'head.php'; ?>
    </head>

    <body id="app">

        <div id="page" class="page">
            <div id="wrap-header" class="wrap-header">
              <header id="masthead" class="site-header">

                <?php require 'app-menu.php'; ?>

              </header>

            </div>

            <div id="wrap-main" class="wrap-main">
```

page.php

```
<?php require 'layouts/header.php'; 

 <!-- Page specific content pulled in here -->

<?php require 'layouts/footer.php'; ?>
```

Comment: You can only over-write what was included, there is no concept of 'back' here. Including something makes it a part of something, no longer separate for arguments sake.

Comment: PHP REQUIREs or INCLUDEs files in the order that they are called, in that sequence. You cannot "go back" into a previously included script and change the outputted html code.

Comment: Ya thats what I thought, I was trying to figure out how wordpress does it. They have an include header but it pulls specific page content for the head for SEO and sharing.

Comment: It likely pulls the data from a database for the header.

Comment: It uses functions that are defined in the include files. The functions take parameters and/or get information from the database, and substitute them into the templates.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of just producing output in the include files, you should define functions. Here's a simple example.

header.php:

```
<?php
function show_header($title) {
    ?>
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>

    <html lang="en">

        <head>
            <title><?php echo $title ?></title>
            <?php require 'head.php'; ?>
        </head>

        <body id="app">

            <div id="page" class="page">
                <div id="wrap-header" class="wrap-header">
                  <header id="masthead" class="site-header">

                    <?php require 'app-menu.php'; ?>

                  </header>

                </div>

                <div id="wrap-main" class="wrap-main">
    <?php
}
```

Then your main page would do:

```
<?php
require('header.php');
show_header("My Home Page");
```